# Arraylist of an object in another object acts like a static?

Tags: java, object, for-loop, arraylist

I have 2 objects, Points and Charges. Inside Points there is an Arraylist of charges. 
I created an array of points where each point has a identical arraylist of charges at FIRST.

```
clist.add(new Charges(2,-1));
clist.add(new Charges(2,-3));
plist.add(new Points("P1",0,-2));
plist.add(new Points("P2",2,-2));
```

Points are into an ArrayList(Points) plist and charges in clist.
Later it stores clist in each of the Points object in plist and then store in pArray in a Class Calculation when will loop through the pArray to call a test method from the Points class.

Then after calculating a test variable by adding variables(x,y from the Points object and the Charges in its arraylist. ) that loops through the arraylist(Points) and Arraylist(Charges) I print out the test variable.

it should print out as:

```
0
-3
1
-1
```

but when i try to print it i get:

```
1
-1
1
-1
```

so the variable that was last looped (1,-1) is also stored in other Points object's cArray like a static variable.
I cant figure out where the problem is. Please help correct this.

Points Class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Points
{
    ArrayList<Charges> cArray;

    int x;
    int y;
    String name;

    public Points(String p,int x1,int y1)
    {
        x=x1;
        y=y1;
        name=p;
    } 

    public ArrayList<Charges> getCArray()
        {return cArray;}
    public void setCArray(ArrayList<Charges> a)
        {cArray=a;}

    public void testCode()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cArray.size();i++)
                {
                    Charges temp = cArray.get(i);
                    int chargex=temp.getX();
                    int chargey= temp.getY();
                    int test = x+y+chargex+chargey;
                    temp.setTest(test);
                    cArray.set(i,temp);
                }
    }

    public void printString()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cArray.size();i++)
            {
            System.out.println(cArray.get(i).getTest());
            }
    }

}
```

Charges Class

```
public class Charges
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int test;

    public Charges(int x1, int y1)
    {
        x=x1;
        y=y1;
    }

    public int getX()
    {return x;}
    public void setX(int x1)
    {x=x1;}

    public int getY()
    {return y;}
    public void setY(int y1)
    {y=y1;}

    public int getTest()
    {return test;}
    public void setTest(int t)
    {test=t;}
    }
```

Calculations Class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Calculations
{
    ArrayList<Points> pArray;

    public ArrayList<Points> getPointArray(){return pArray;}
    public void setPointArray(ArrayList<Points> p){pArray=p;}

    public void allTest()
    {
    ArrayList<Points> temparray= new ArrayList<Points>();   
        for(int j=0;j<pArray.size();j++)
        {
        Points point =pArray.get(j);
        point.testCode();
        temparray.add(point);
        }
    pArray=temparray;
    }
}
```

Client class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    ArrayList<Charges> clist = new ArrayList<Charges>();
    ArrayList<Points> plist = new ArrayList<Points>();
    clist.add(new Charges(2,-1));
    clist.add(new Charges(2,-3));
    plist.add(new Points("P1",0,-2));
    plist.add(new Points("P2",2,-2));



    ArrayList<Points> list= new ArrayList<Points>();            
    for(int i=0;i<plist.size();i++)
        {
        ArrayList<Charges> chlist= clist;
        Points point = plist.get(i);
        point.setCArray(chlist);
        list.add(point);
        }
    Calculations calc=new Calculations();
    calc.setPointArray(list);
    calc.allTest();
    for(int k=0;k<calc.getPointArray().size();k++)
        {
        Points p=calc.getPointArray().get(k);
        p.printString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [(JAVA) objects with an arraylist of another object that is acting static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315751/java-objects-with-an-arraylist-of-another-object-that-is-acting-static)

Comment: Please take your time to fix your original question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: i've deleted the other question because it was too messy and had to create a sample of the original code to better show my problem

Comment: Btw to print an `ArrayList` you can just do `System.out.println(cArray)`.

Comment: yes I know, but printing the arraylist is not the problem,its that all cArray are the same no matter the Points object.

Answer (score 0):

If figured out how to get around the problem by storing the calculated test variable in an array in the Point Class instead of keep it in the Charges class. I figure that the cArrays' share the same reference which is why they are overwriting all of them.